# Manipulation sender e-mail-address with invitation

Tags: azure, guest

when inviting a guest to our tenant using the "azure ad guest invitation"-procedure, the new guest will receive an e-mail to accept the invitation (and choose a username and a passwort...).
This invitation will always use the sender e-mail-address "invite@microsoft.com", which may be fine in many cases but not for us.
We have a secured e-mail-system for the people we want to invite as guest which will only allow to send mails to these people when the domain of the sender is one of our domains (e.g. mydomain.com). Mails from other domains are not delivered and there is no chance to add "microsoft.com" as a valid domain.
So to invite guests from that system we will need to change the invitation-sender-e-mail-adress from "invite@microsoft.com" to (e.g.) "invite@mydomian.com" so the invitation can be delivered. Any ideas if that is possible and where in azure to do that?
Thanks and all the best from Berlin, Germany
Carsten

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to change the sender address. However, you do not need the email to accept the invite, you can retrieve the invite URL from Azure AD and send it to them yourself. You can also just have the user login to your tenant and it will accept the invite then.